# How to integrate projectM in VLC?

Tags: vlc

I have installed both VLC and projectM (PulseAudio) from the Software Center, but I the visualizations that appear in Audio -> Visualizations have not changed. How can I launch the projectM visualizations from VLC.

(I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.)

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem with Ubuntu 14.04. Found answers on the net suggesting to mute & unmute all pulseaudio's sources (manually or via command-line), to delete pulseaudio's configuration etc, tried all mention above with no luck. Visualisations still not paying attention to music.

Answer (score 3):

Project M is not automatically integrated into VLC (or any application that I know of). You would need to find a plugin for the application that allows you to use Project M's visualizations.

To my knowledge, there is no existing plugin for VLC that allows you to do this. So, like spm says, you will need to start `projectM-pulseaudio` separately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried starting projectM separately, but it does not integrate with VLC, this is, the visualisations do not sync with the music. However, I have projectM installed at work with other operating system and the projectM option appears directly in the Audio -> Visualisations menu. I wonder if that would be possible in Ubuntu.

Comment: @granadajose is this other operating system Windows? Not every media player supports Project M, and on different systems, different features are supported.

Comment: yes it is Windows, but the media player that I use on Windows it's also the VLC player. I assumed that the same player would offer the same options even in different operating systems and all I had to do was to do the proper setup.

Answer (score 2):

You can't as far as I know.

The command to start the visualizations is `projectM-pulseaudio` just type that into a terminal or command window and it'll open in a separate window.